# Too many math alphabets in beamer

Tags: fonts, siunitx, chemmacros

This `beamer` attempt produces the error "Too many math alphabets used in version normal.". Using the `article` class produces no error as does removing either `chemmacros` or `siunitx`, but I need those packages.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{greek=fourier}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{helvet, mathpazo}%suggested by siunitx


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\num{1+2i}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: not sure why you need so many fonts, but using xelatex or lualatex is one option as the document runs without error then.

Comment: I just used some of the packages the `siunitx` documentation suggests. Removing the `\usepackage{helvet, mathpazo}` line throws a single error, while keeping it throws two. 

At this point I'm considering to give up on pdfLaTeX and use XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`. Compiles for me, then.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{greek=fourier}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{helvet, mathpazo}%suggested by siunitx


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\num{1+2i}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are a god..